# Redis lexicographic search in reverse order

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, servicestack.redis

I have a sorted set in Redis where I store the userid and last login timestamp.

Adding to sorted set (using below code) works like a charm using *StackExchange.Redis* for C# and I can see the values added in *redis-cli*.

```
IDatabase rdb = redis.GetDatabase();
rdb.SortedSetAdd("LOGINS", "userid:timestamp", 0.0, CommandFlags.None);
```

I now need to query Redis DB to get last login timestamp for a userid.

In *redis-cli*, I can run below query to get the last login timestamp for a userid:

```
zrevrangebylex LOGINS "[userid\xff" [userid LIMIT 0 1
```

However, I did not find a way to run this command in either *StackExchange.Redis* or *ServiceStack.Redis* to do lexicographic search in reverse order.

How to run above *redis-cli* query in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: that command appears to have been omitted. I'll [add a github issue for the next deploy](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/316). For now, you could use Lua (`ScriptEvaluate`) to invoke it (ungainly, but it should work).

Comment: Thanks Marc for adding github issue for this and suggesting a workaround. For others having this issue, this is the how we can call Lua using StackExchange.Redis      `const string script = "return redis.call('zrevrangebylex', 'LOGINS', '[0301861887\xff', '[0301861887', 'LIMIT', '0', '1')";
  var prepared = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
  var result = (string[])db.ScriptEvaluate(prepared);
  foreach (var res in result)              
    Console.WriteLine(res);`